# How to use $obj->A::a instead of $obj->$b

Tags: php

Question is very simple. How could i use somthing like `$obj->A::a` where `A::a` is a constant string that is the name of one of `obj`'s property?

Lets look to this simple code:

```
class A{
 const a='b';
}
class B{
    public $b='somthing';
}

$k='b';
$obj=new B();
```

Now both these codes are equal:

```
var_dump(A::a);  //==string(1) "b"
var_dump($k);    //==string(1) "b"
```

Now I can use below code,
    echo $obj->$k;   //Output is: somthing
But this code is not working:

```
echo $obj->A::a; //Error
```

I need something similar to above code because I have a lot `const`t similar to.

Feel free for editing the title, Really i don't know how should I name it!

Comment: `echo $obj->{A::a};` will do the job you're looking for, if I've got your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because class B does not have any public attribute called A. Therefore you cannot access it, which is what you're trying to do by doing `$obj->A`. This is logical if you think about the order of calls when you do something like `$obj->methodA()->methodB()`.

The proper way to access it is rather `$obj->{A::a}`.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
$x = A::a;
echo $obj->$x;
```

Comment: It will work ,and me found the answer in a chancy manner. thanks to your answer. you can see my answer

Comment: I did but stackoverflow said wait a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the answer.
Answer is very very simple. Just add `{}` to `const` (`A::a`) like this:

```
echo $obj->{A::a};
```